# Jade If Statement Not Working With Variable

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I'm trying to compare the value of a variable with a constant string, and I can't get the if statement to work properly. I'm using Angular.js with Jade.

Here's my code.

```
ol
  li(ng-repeat = "notification in notificationData")
    - var typeOfNotification = '{{ notification.typeOfNotification }}'
    p #{ typeOfNotification }
    -if (typeOfNotification == 'like')
      p LIKED
    -else
      p ELSE
```

This gives the output

```
like

ELSE

follow

ELSE

like

ELSE

like

ELSE

follow

ELSE
```

The if statement is never evaluated to being true, even though the `p #{ typeOfNotification }` in the line above shows that the variable contains the value `like` for some cases. How should I change my Jade code to get this working properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is: the evaluation of Jade will be finished before Angular is initialized.
So you can't mix it!

Do you render the Jade template on server side? Or do you compile it to JavaScript and load the template on the client?

For the first version you can't do it, for the second you need to init Angular before you render the template into the DOM with Jade and maybe pass the context to the Jade template.

Anyway, you can solve it if you extract the logic out of Jade into a your Angular code.
I'm not familiar with Angular, so the `ng-call` is my pseudo Angular directive, which can call a simple function which is defined and accessible in the global scope and puts the returned value in the elements node:

```
script.
  var getNotificationType = function(notification) {
    return notification.typeOfNotification
  }
  var typeIsLike = function(n) {
    var type = getNotificationType(n);
    if (type === 'like') {
      return 'LIKED';
    }
    return 'ELSE';
  }
  var foo = "bar";


ol
  li(ng-repeat = "notification in notificationData")
  p(ng-call = "getNotificationType(notification)")
  p(ng-call = "typeIsLike(notification)")
```

---

BTW: you could write `p= typeOfNotification` instead of `p #{ typeOfNotification }`
(if it would work ;)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use variable from angular to jade **if** but you can use angular **ng-if** in jade.

```
ol
  li(ng-repeat = "notification in notificationData")
    p(ng-if= "notification.typeOfNotification == 'like'") LIKED 
    p(ng-if= "notification.typeOfNotification != 'like'") ELSE
```